# PuTTY and how to keep alive telnet session

Tags: session, telnet, putty

I need to keep alive telnet session in PuTTY but I can't still figure it out how to do it. I have this setting:
[image]
[image]

And if I try for example just:

```
$ GET /signout HTTP/1.1
```

then if is checked "Never close window on exit" the result is inactive window and if is checked "Close window only on clean exit" then it closes window after request. But I need for example on the first request give something into the session and on another request print it what is in session. How can I setting it? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrong Keep-Alive.  TCP keepalive is a feature of the TCP stack that periodically (default is every 4 hours, if I remember correctly) sends an empty data packet just to make sure the other side still has its end of the connection open.  It's a network-level feature and will not under any circumstances cause the server (or client) to *not* close the connection.

http://tldp.org/HOWTO/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/overview.html

HTTP Keep-Alive is a line in the request header requesting that the server not close the connection after responding to this request so that further requests can be sent along the same TCP connection.  The server may choose not to honor this request.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection